# Getting error while creating archetype in eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create Maven project. And adding archetype jersey-quickstart-webapp I am getting following error.

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2

Comment: There;s not enough information here for someone to try and help you. Please post your Maven POM and what command you were trying to execute.

Comment: Based on your post I assume you have download/proxy/firewall issues..I bet there have been messages during the download...This can only be acknowledged by showing the whole log output which is not there...so this is only an educated guess...